# css pseudo class last child issue

Tags: css

I have website
http://yournextleap.com/fresher-jobs
Please find out last div having HTML

```
<div data-recommendation="" data-id="3790" data-guidance="" data-bucket="jobs">
<div class="inn">
/* Some code*/
</div>
</div>
```

.inn having dashed bottom border
and it's parent div is dynamically generated

**What I want:**

1. The last DIV .inn must have border: none;
2. for That I tried :last-child
3. I don't want to use JS or Jquery

I added class for main div (temporarily I removed it); Now ther is only `<div>` 
it was

```
<div class="main">
```

that's it, Here was my css

```
.main:last-child .inn{
border: none;}
```

But it's not working

Comment: `.main:last-child`, not `main:last-child`

Comment: yes my mistake but i used .main:last-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i have tested and made the following changes in your css

```
div.hero-unit div.recommendation + div div:last-child div.inn {border:none !important;}
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome i am testing the same for IE This will work only in IE 9+ browsers IE 7 and IE 8 will not support this CSS selectors.

will explain the pattern here.

1. `div.hero-unit` is to select the parent div
2. `div.recommendation` is to select the child inside `div.hero-unit`
3. `+ div` will select the immediate next div
4. `div:last-child` will select the last child inside the div the one we have selected in point 3
5. `div.inn` setting the property `border:none` with `!important` so that the other borders are not applied because `border:none` will be given the highest priority due to `!important`.

Hope it helps to every read.. Best of luck

Comment: What's the point of having `!important` and that empty comment?

Comment: nothing is related to empty comment it is just i copied my code. and `!important` will force the div to apply this css and exclude all the other. i will remove the empty comment. nothing to do with it.

Comment: No, that's not what `!important` does.

Comment: so can you please explain what `!important` does so that we understand it more clearly. As a profession i am not a HTML designer i may be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm assuming you had:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div data-recommendation="" data-id="3790" data-guidance="" data-bucket="jobs">
            <div class="inn">
            /* Some code*/
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If that's the case, you need:

```
    .main div:last_child .inn {
        border:none;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is right but Chandrakant has removed `class=main` from the div and now there is no more `div.main` :)